# Why does redirecting StandardOutput of GAWK always prepend fstat

Tags: process, output, io-redirection

I have following code to read and redict the output of gawk to a textfile (instead of doing this with shell-execute and using `>`):

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                       {
                         FileName = "gawk.exe",
                         Arguments = $@"-F ""{separator}"" -f ""{scriptFullFileName}"" ""{inputFullFileName}""",
                         UseShellExecute = false,
                         WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
                         RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                         CreateNoWindow = true
                       };
using (var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
{
  using (var streamReader = process.StandardOutput)
  {
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

Inspecting `result` afterwards, it always starts with the following lines:

> fstat < 0: fd = 0
>   fstat < 0: fd = 2

Whereas executing *gawk.exe* from the shell, these lines are not present.

What am I doing wrong - or better, how can I get rid of these 2 lines without additional parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very issue is connected to the used version of gawk.exe, which was [3.1.6.2962](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).
With [4.1.3](http://www.klabaster.com/freeware.htm) this problem does not occur.