# Calling AWK inside Gnuplot produces two extra lines

Tags: windows, awk, cmd, gnuplot

I am using AWK to preprocess files for plotting and fitting in Gnuplot 5.2 on Windows 10. e.g. like this:

```
plot '<awk "{print}" file1.dat file2.dat'
```

While `fit` works fine, `plot` yields this message:

```
Bad data on line 1 of file <awk "{print}" file1.dat file2.dat
```

I took a look at the bad data with `print system('awk "{print}" file1.dat file2.dat')` which shows that there are two extra lines infront of the data, which I can even reproduce with a minimal `print system('awk ""')` which gives

```
fstat < 0: fd = 0
fstat < 0: fd = 2
```

Of course, if I just want to extract a number out of the AWK command, I can do something like

```
sum = real(substr(system('awk "{sum+=$2} END {print sum}" file1.dat'), 37,-1))
```

While this is annoying, it works. But I have not found any work around for `plot`. Even more I would like a solution that avoids the extra lines from the beginning. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Here, I have two more test cases that might provide information:

1. If I run AWK in CMD, the extra lines are not there.
2. Other CMD commands also do not procude the lines in gnuplot, i.e. if I call `print system('echo test')`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with gnuplot 5.2

Comment: @kvantour Do you also run on Windows?

Comment: I don't know awk, but my guess would be that `plot '<awk "{print}" file1.dat file2.dat'` might simply somehow append the two files, correct? Why using awk and creating problems which you possibly might not have with gnuplot alone. What is actually your final goal which you want to achieve? I haven't found a question mark in your question ;-).

Comment: Windows is rather different (poor compared to Linux) when it comes to quoting. FWIW, especially with `awk`, I often put the script unquoted in a text file called `script.awk` and run it with `awk -f script.awk` and it gets around all the issues.

Comment: @theozh I've added the question mark, thanks! ;-) What I want to do, are multiple things. I have one task where I append the two files but I shift the first column of the second file by a constant. In another one I want to use data columns from two files to do computations between them. In my tests, the AWKing does exactly what I want it to do. I just didn't want to bother you with details here, because it's really about the ```fstat``` lines.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's a very good idea which I tried on the spot. Unfortunately, it seems to make things worse. ```print system('awk -f sript.awk file1.dat file2.dat')``` gives now only the ```fstat``` lines but not the output of the script, which gives the correct output when I call it in CMD. In addition, I believe I did manage quoting ;-)

Comment: I think this is an issue on `awk` and is not on `gnuplot`. Did you check this link [Why does redirecting StandardOutput of GAWK always prepend fstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067123/why-does-redirecting-standardoutput-of-gawk-always-prepend-fstat)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem when I tried to extract a value from awk script. e.g.

```
gnuplot> a = system('gawk "BEGIN { nnt=0;}; {nnt = $2>nnt?$2:nnt; } END{ print nnt }" load.dat ')
gnuplot> print a
fstat < 0: fd = 0
fstat < 0: fd = 2
3
gnuplot>
```

By the following two steps to remove the two annoying extra lines,
Step 1: passing data file using pipe operator

```
gnuplot> a = system('gawk "BEGIN { nnt=0;}; {nnt = $2>nnt?$2:nnt; } END{ print nnt }" load.dat ')
gnuplot> print a
fstat < 0: fd = 0
fstat < 0: fd = 2
3
gnuplot>
```

Step 2: combining stdout /stderr together

```
gnuplot> a = system('gawk "BEGIN { nnt=0;}; {nnt = $2>nnt?$2:nnt; } END{ print nnt }" load.dat ')
gnuplot> print a
fstat < 0: fd = 0
fstat < 0: fd = 2
3
gnuplot>
```

Then the problem can be fixed.